# Sobolev spaces on non-compact manifolds -- independence on charts

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Are there some standard references where basic facts about fractional-order (or at least integer-order) Sobolev spaces on non-compact manifolds are treated? 
More precisely I would like to be able to refer to a theorem saying that for any two choices of (countable number of) charts the resulting norms are equivalent.